# Ruby on Rails String to OpenStruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, openstruct

I have the following OpenStruct object but if I call .class on it is a string. How do I turn it back into a OpenStruct object?

```
[
 #<OpenStruct source="hkepc.com", visits="8", visitBounceRate="37.5", avgTimeOnSite="199.375", pageviews="25", pageviewsPerVisit="3.125">, 
 #<OpenStruct source="1st-tag.co.uk", visits="6", visitBounceRate="100.0", avgTimeOnSite="0.0", pageviews="6", pageviewsPerVisit="1.0">, 
 #<OpenStruct source="facebook.com", visits="5", visitBounceRate="80.0", avgTimeOnSite="8.2", pageviews="6", pageviewsPerVisit="1.2">
]
```

Comment: This is not an OpenStruct object its an Array

Comment: Can you please post a working example to reproduce the problem?

Comment: so could I just do split?

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins the `Object#class` method always returns a `String` (http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Object.html#method-i-class) - am I misunderstanding what you are asking? Also, you've posted an `Array` here as opposed to a single `OpenStruct`, so I assumed you are referring to an element of this array.

Comment: @AndreasKavountzis: no, it returns a `class`.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev good catch, read the docs but wrote the wrong thing. Updating comment, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A little bit hacky, but I think achieves your goal:

```
require 'ostruct'

string_array = '[
 #<OpenStruct source="hkepc.com", visits="8", visitBounceRate="37.5", avgTimeOnSite="199.375", pageviews="25", pageviewsPerVisit="3.125">, 
 #<OpenStruct source="1st-tag.co.uk", visits="6", visitBounceRate="100.0", avgTimeOnSite="0.0", pageviews="6", pageviewsPerVisit="1.0">, 
 #<OpenStruct source="facebook.com", visits="5", visitBounceRate="80.0", avgTimeOnSite="8.2", pageviews="6", pageviewsPerVisit="1.2">
]'

string_array.gsub(/(\n|#<OpenStruct|\[|\]|\s+)/, '').split('>,').map do |attrs|
  struct_attrs = attrs.split(',')
  attrs = struct_attrs.inject({}) do |hash, elem|
    hash[elem.split('=').first] = elem.split('=').last.gsub('"', '')
    hash
  end

  OpenStruct.new(attrs)
end
```

Comment: but at the moment the array is actually a string, if you understand what i mean?

Comment: Ah, OK sorry that wasn't clear from the OP. So that mean that these are the `.to_s` versions of these objects most likely... I'm not sure of an approach that would allow you to reconstruct them as `OpenStruct`s without having to parse out the attributes (as mentioned in your comment above).

Comment: That is pretty close to it! but it seems to add extra quotes and slashes?


#<OpenStruct source="\"youtube.com\"", visits="\"71\"", visitBounceRate="\"39.436619718309856\"", avgTimeOnSite="\"83.29577464788733\"", pageviews="\"192\"", pageviewsPerVisit="\"2.704225352112676\"">

Comment: @MaxRose-Collins answer updated. Hopefully that works!

Comment: How would I preserve spaces within each `<OpenStruct>` ? For example `#<OpenStruct country="UnitedStates", visits="425">` United States should have a space between it?

Comment: You'll probably need to remove `\s+` from the RegExp, so `string_array.gsub(/(\n|#<OpenStruct|\[|\]|\s+)/, '')` becomes `string_array.gsub(/(\n|#<OpenStruct|\[|\])/, '')`

Comment: I never did work out this problem. When I remove the \s+ everything is blank