# How to convert string to openstruct

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, openstruct

I have a string which is an openstruct object. How can I convert it to again to an openstruct?

```
#<OpenStruct gmail=#<Gmail::Client0xbe112w (abcd@y.com) connected>>
```

This is a string how can I again convert it to the openstruct object, so that I can access the value

```
List item
```

Comment: There is no direct way to convert strings to `OpenStruct` - if the string is some kind of structure to it (like JSON or XML or YAML), then, one can write code to parse to a hash and use that to create `OpenStruct` using `OpenStruct::marshal_load`

Comment: this is  a string #<OpenStruct gmail=#<Gmail::Client0xbe18qwe (abcd@ycom) connected>> Andrey Deineko

Comment: Check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22765419/ruby-on-rails-string-to-openstruct), it's something alike.

Comment: I checked that before posting the question,it does not work. - Daneil

Comment: `Gmail::Client...` is not an OpenStruct - what you are asking is impossible.

Comment: I want to pass a gmail object to sidekiq as parameters,so i am putting them in openstruct and passing to sidekiq as params - Wand Maker

Comment: `Gmail::Client` represents a connection to gmail - you cannot pass that around like a Hash or OpenStruct - the `sidekiq` worker should connect to Gmail on its own to get hold of such an object.

Comment: If i don't pass the object how will the worker get it to know about it, if you have any suggestions can you please tell me

Comment: I am not an expert on sidekiq, you need to pass simple params and not connection objects.  You can post a separate question if your problem is not parsing String to get OpenStruct.  This question seems to be [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)